# Downloading a file with terraform provider http fails

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

**The context**

I try to download a file in an Azure Devops repository in a terraform project.

I use this code:

```
provider "http" {}

data "http" "file" {
  url = "https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_git/<repository>/test.txt?ref=main"

  request_headers = {
    Authorization = "Basic ${base64encode("PAT:XXXXXXXX")}"
  }
}

resource "local_file" "fchiertest" {
  content  = data.http.file.response_body
  filename = "${path.root}/test.txt"
}
```

The file is test.txt and is in the root.
I get the url from cloning command to be sure of the syntaxe

**What I get**

I get a 404 error.

**What I tested**

These urls:

1. https://dev.azure.com///_git/?ref=mainépath=/test.txt
2. https://dev.azure.com///_git///test.txt?ref=main
3. https://@dev.azure.com///_git//test.txt?ref=main
4. git::https://dev.azure.com///_git//test.txt?ref=main

I also tested:

```
  request_headers = {
    Authorization = "Basic ${base64encode("XXXXXXXXX")}"
  }
```

My token has full access

**What I need**

Does anybody know the right syntax?

Thank you

Comment: Does this happen only with `https://dev.azure.com/`? What if you try to get any other file from a regular, publicly accessible website?

Comment: works fine with:
url="https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform"

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution (in fact Copilot!!):

This url works:

https://dev.azure.com///_apis/git/repositories/multiModule/items?path=%2Ftest.txt&api-version=6.0